# Twitter Bootstrap Inset Panel With Uniform Padding/Margins?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to make a webpage with a background image and an inlaid opaque panel.

I'm trying to get the panel to stretch all the way down to the bottom of the page, with a few em padding at the bottom.

I also want the padding to be uniform all around the panel. I need it to stretch down to fit whatever display it is in, and need it to be dynamic.

I've tried tons of stuff with height in the html, body, and panel style sections (`min-height`, `max-height`, `height`), but it only seems to work when I hardcode pixel values. Below is my css and html.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do something like this?

```
        html {
            height: 100%;
            background: url(images/background_blurred.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            background: transparent;
            color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
        }

        .panel {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.8);
        }


<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">


            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: so u want the panel to occupy the complete screen???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply height:100% to your `container` and `row` div also.

```
.container, .row{height:100%}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/pL00uu2s/)